# What IP address is used to Ping

Tags: ip, php

I'm having some doubt. I'm getting IP address by using PHP, and whatever IP it is giving when I track that it gives correct information about the IP.
And when I ping that IP address, 100% packet get lost, Why?
And scanning that IP address using Advanced Port Scanner it shows nothing, Why?
Can Anyone make me understand what IP should I get to find the open PORT and can ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And when I ping that IP address, 100% packet get lost, Why?

Possible reasons: Firewall dropping all incoming ICMP traffic, or system is behind a NAT and ICMP is not forwarded.

> And scanning that IP address using Advanced Port Scanner it shows nothing, Why?

You are scanning a private-range IP address and it is unreachable, or a firewall is blocking your probes.

> Can Anyone make me understand what IP should I get to find the open PORT and can ping.

You cannot find open ports through selecting a specific IP or pinging an IP.  ICMP is not TCP or UDP and does not use the notion of ports.

Comment: so, how should I find the open ports??

Comment: There may not be any.

Comment: @AnsariAbdullah You need to use a port scanner like `nmap`.

Comment: @gardenhead, are you sure whatever IP I got from using PHP, and I scan that IP using nmap will work?

Comment: I mean, will it shows Open Ports?

Comment: @AnsariAbdullah - As the answer says, ICMP doesn't use ports.  There are two common port types: TCP ports, and UDP ports.  (There are also uncommon ones, namely what I know of is SCTP ports.)  ping uses ICMP, and uses IP (so it uses IP addresses), but it doesn't use TCP or UDP or SCTP.  So, just forget about ports.  ping never acts with ports in any way.  (However, ping does use ICMP message types... some software may show the ICMP message type in a data field labelled "port".  It's a handy method, since TCP/UDP/SCTP doesn't use ICMP message types. Still, ICMP doesn't use/interact with ports.)

Comment: isn't there any say to see TCP ports?

Comment: can you please share the link of any site, that from I learn all about how network works, just what are you telling now!

Comment: I'm still 16, but I'm very very interested in these things

Comment: @AnsariAbdullah Yes, scan that IP with nmap. Though I've no idea what you mean when you say you got an IP from PHP.

Comment: I have created a site, when you visit that it grab the visitors IP address and save it in a text file, that's what I'm telling!!